# How to call method i sweetalert 2

Tags: angular, sweetalert, sweetalert2

In my angular 4 project I am using a theme with sweetalert 2, I want to call my method when user click on the confirm button, but it seems that I can't call any method inside then function

```
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function () {

  // I want to call my method here but I can't do this.myMethod()

})
```

I know It's not the angular sweetalert but is it possible to make it work without change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the arrow function notation `() =>`. When you use the `function` keyword, you loose the access to `this`. Change your code to the below instead:

```
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(()=> {

  this.myMethod(); // this should execute now

})
```

Comment: Glad to help @m007 :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer helped me too, although I had to solve how to catch the "*Uncaught in promise*" error. I thought I'd just add it here for completion if anyone found it helpful using the cancelButton.

```
swal({
   //code         
}).then(()=> {
   //code
},(error: any) => console.log(error));
```