# Runtime error: unable to resume activity. TypeError :this.callResume is not a function in nativescript angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

At [resume Event](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/application-lifecycle.html#use-application-events) I have to call this method `this.callResume()`. When I'm calling that method I'm getting runtime error:

> TypeError :this.callResume is not a function

I don't know how to call a method from resume method in lifecycle.I placed resume method in constructor.

```
  constructor() {

  applicationOn(resumeEvent, function (args: ApplicationEventData) {


    if (args.android) {
        // For Android applications, args.android is an android activity class.
        console.log("Activity: " + args.android);

      this.callResume();

    } else if (args.ios) {
        // For iOS applications, args.ios is UIApplication.
        console.log("UIApplication: " + args.ios);
     }
    });

}

  callResume():void{

  console.log("ResumeCalled", "Test");

  }
```

Comment: Use the arrow function notation `()=>` instead of `function`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45758744/1791913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tte arrow function notation `()=>` instead of `function`. Chane your code to following:

```
constructor() {

  applicationOn(resumeEvent,  (args: ApplicationEventData) => {
    if (args.android) {
        // For Android applications, args.android is an android activity class.
        console.log("Activity: " + args.android);

      this.callResume();

    } else if (args.ios) {
        // For iOS applications, args.ios is UIApplication.
        console.log("UIApplication: " + args.ios);
     }
    });

}
```